# Is it possible to retrieve the Cognito verification code of a new user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I've looked every where and couldn't find the answer.

I'm trying to create a user using `adminCreateUser`, which works.

But I would like to handle the email logic separately from Cognito. Is there a way to retrieve the verification code for that user so I can email it myself?

I've also tried looking at the `signUp` but I can't prevent emails through that.

Answer (score 1):

You're in luck as at some point in the last year, cognito released the [custom email sender trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-email-sender.html).

No big announcement, no console support and, contrary to cloudformation documentation, it is supported there or through the cli (or http api for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `customEmailSender` trigger (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-email-sender.html) — however, at this stage, it can be painful to integrate.

It does not have proper support with Cloudformation or any infrastructure-as-code services ([Serverless issue](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/8889), [AWS CDK issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/15863) etc.) — but it can be done through some custom resources in AWS CDK (see the linked issue).

Understandably, it is a matter of time before this can be done with high-level constructs through these services.